# Drupal 7 how to display $user_picture in node

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming

the Theme I am using (Plasma) has an option in the settings to display the users profile picture, but when I select it, it only shows the picture in the comments.

When I looked at the node.tpl.php in the theme it does not output the $user_picture variable.

So I tried adding this variable myself just below the `<header>` tag as it is in the comment.tpl.php but the image is displayed above the post, rather than inline with left alignment.

I tried wrapping the $user_picture in `<align=left> </align>` but this did not work.

So how do I show the picture as left aligned with the header and text of the post wrapped around the user profile picture.

Thanks
Simon

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution if you are using the the Plasma Theme, but it will probably work on most themes.

In the Theme folder edit the CSS file and add the following code

```
.node .user-picture{
float: left;
padding: 4px;
border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
margin-right: 7px;
margin-bottom: 7px;
}


.content .user-picture{
float: left;
padding: 4px;
border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
margin-right: 7px;
margin-bottom: 7px;
}
```

Then in your node.tpl.php add the following just above  `print render($content);`

```
print $user_picture;
```

This will put the user picture at the top left of the content for every node and teaser. You can still turn off the user profile picture in the theme settings.